# Syntax error in INSERT INTO statement

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, ms-access

I want to insert new value to Access table I am using this code

```
Public cmd As New OleDbCommand
Public CMDB As New OleDbCommandBuilder
Dim da As OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter
Dim con As New OleDb.OleDbConnection

Protected Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click

    con.ConnectionString = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=|DataDirectory|learn_english.mdb"
    con.Open()
    cmd = New OleDbCommand("insert into quiz (question, option1, option2, option3, option4, answer, level) values(@question, @op1, @op2, @op3, @op4, @answer ,@level)", con)
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@question", TextBox1.Text)
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@op1", TextBox2.Text)
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@op2", TextBox3.Text)
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@op3", TextBox4.Text)
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@op4", TextBox5.Text)
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@answer", TextBox6.Text)
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@level",DropDownList1.SelectedValue)

    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
    con.Close()
End Sub
```

But I'm getting the error "Syntax error in INSERT INTO statement"

Comment: level is a reserved word, escape it like so: `"...[Level]) VALUES (..."` all those DB objects at the top should be used once and disposed, not declared globally for reuse

Comment: Duplicate of [Microsoft Access does not like a table field name in a SQL Query](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8812652/microsoft-access-does-not-like-a-table-field-name-in-a-sql-query)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OleDbCommand does not **support named parameters**. You have to replace your `@PARAM` by `?`. (see [OleDbCommand.Parameters](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.oledb.oledbcommand.parameters.aspx) in MSDN.)

> The OLE DB .NET Provider does not support named parameters for passing
>   parameters to an SQL statement or a stored procedure called by an
>   OleDbCommand when CommandType is set to Text. In this case, the
>   question mark (?) placeholder must be used.

```
cmd = New OleDbCommand("insert into quiz (question, option1, option2, option3, option4, answer, [level]) values(?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ? ,?)", con)
cmd.Parameters.Add(TextBox1.Text)
cmd.Parameters.Add(TextBox2.Text)
cmd.Parameters.Add(TextBox3.Text)
cmd.Parameters.Add(TextBox4.Text)
cmd.Parameters.Add(TextBox5.Text)
cmd.Parameters.Add(TextBox6.Text)
cmd.Parameters.Add(DropDownList1.SelectedValue)
```

I think this code should do the trick!

Comment: actually, you *can* use named parameters but OleDB just treats them as positional placeholders, so you have to Add or AddWithValue in the same order.  It can lead to errors if you define them in one order and add in another.

Comment: strange thing, didn't use OleDb quite a while. Wonder why MSDN did state that this is not possible? Do you have any resource for that @Plutonix

Comment: just that I do it all the time.  I tend to use "@p1, @p2 ..." so I dont even *think* to use them as actual named params.  The numerals help keep straight which var you are working with.